# I want to remove unwanted blank page after I make too long footnote

Tags: beamer

As I write down my title, I want to remove unwanted blank page between first page and third page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text which I would like to write down.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Let us write this in terms of creation and annihilation operators, using \footnote{$\phi(\vec{x}) = \int  d\tilde{p}\left( e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}a_{\vec{p}} + e^{-  i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger} \right)$}{eq.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to write down footnote for some equation, but it is sometimes too long to write down in footnote space. So far I searched similar problem but I can't find proper answer to solve this problem.

What I want to know is how do I remove unwanted blank page or how do I increase footnote space. How can I do that?

Comment: Is dropping the `\left` and `\right` instructions in the footnote material an option?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a footnote, a device that I can't recommend for presentations.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\left(` and `\right)` seems to be the problem. Try using `\big(` and `\big)`. It does not create a blank page. 
Or you may want to add
`\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{24pt}}` %%change number of pt as required
in the preamble and use `\left(` and `\right)`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{24pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text which I would like to write down.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Let us write this in terms of creation and annihilation operators, using \footnote{$\phi(\vec{x}) = \int  d\tilde{p}\left( e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}a_{\vec{p}} + e^{-  i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger} \right)$}{eq.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. I solve the problem after I follow your suggestion. Have a good day :)